# Getting error in SQL Server 2008 R2 rsItemNotfound Error

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have installed reporting services in SQL Server 2008 R2 and configured reporting services too successfully.

I am getting an error when hitting the webURL.

German:

> Das /-Element wurde nicht gefunden. (rsItemNotFound) Onlinehilfe

in English:

> The / element was not found. ( rsItemNotFound ) Online Help

Regards,
Chaithanya

Comment: Can any one have idea on above error and assist us on this issue..

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9702c54f-8200-4f26-b19f-1080f025017e/reporting-services-error-rsitemnotfound?forum=tfssetup